# Pass a ViewBag instance to a HiddenFor field in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.hiddenfor

Using ASP.NET MVC and Razor, I'm trying to pass a ViewBag item from the controller to a HiddenFor field (using Razor). I get the following message: Extension methods cannot by dynamically dispatched.

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.PortfolioId, ViewBag.PortfolioId);
```

Comment: Does you model have a property `PortfolioId`? I assume you do not understand `@Html.HiddenFor()` - the second parameter is for rendering the html attributes

Answer (score 24):

You are getting this error because ViewBag is dynamic type. You can use ViewModel instead of ViewBag to solve this problem.

Alternatively you can use following or plain html as suggested by iceburg:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", (string)ViewBag.PortfolioId)
```

Comment: here, the string "id" is used as the hidden inputs id and name attributes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do it with the helper but you can achieve the same markup useing plain html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PortfolioId" id="PortfolioId" value="@ViewBag.PortfolioId" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.HiddenFor(i =>i.PortfolioId, htmlAttributes: new { @Value = ViewBag.PortfolioId })`

will solve your problem if your "PortfolioId" is really a property model.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity! Indeed this is what you need when your property is part of a model (as is in all mvc cshtmls (:_)